# String reference to worksheet works, but string variable does not

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm copying worksheets from one workbook to another. If I copy them individually, the cells have a reference to the external copied workbook. If I copy them all at the same time, the cell references will refer to the worksheets in the new workbook.

If I hard code the list of worksheets from the external workbook, everything works fine.

```
closedBook.Worksheets("dog", "cat", "cow").Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
```

If I put the list of worksheets in a variable and use it instead, it dies.

```
strSheets = "dog", "cat", "cow"
closedBook.Worksheets(strSheets).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `Array` here.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
dim T(1 to 3) as string

T(1) = "dog"
T(2) = "cat"
T(3) = "cow"

for x = 1 to 3
closedBook.Worksheets(x).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
Next x
```

By the way: In your code, you seem to have forgotten the second " after cat.

Comment: Or more simply: `closedBook.Worksheets(Array("dog", "cat", "cow")).Copy...`

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks.

Yes. That works and the examples are all over the place. But I don't know how many worksheets are in the other workbook. I'm looping through and collecting the names. That's how I'm populating strSheets.

Comment: This is also copying the worksheets one at a time instead of all at once. That method will make all cell references point to the external workbook. I need to have them point to the worksheets in the new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> strSheets = "dog", "cat", "cow"
> ```

You're assigning 3 string literals to 1 identifier, and that is illegal.

No `String` can hold multiple string values: you want an *array* of strings, and you can wrap that into a `Variant`:

```
Dim sheeNames As Variant
```

And assign it to an array using the `Array` function:

```
sheetNames = Array("dog", "cat", "cow")
```

And now you can use your variant array of sheet names as intended:

```
closedBook.Worksheets(sheetNames).Copy  ...
```

Note the absence of a `str` prefix (see [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) for what should be the final coffin in Systems Hungarian notation), and the pluralized name.

Can also be inlined:

```
closedBook.Worksheets(Array("dog", "cat", "cow")).Copy  ...
```

Comment: Is that a question?